# How to --enable-xmlreader in PHP

Tags: php

I am running Fedora 10 and have php 5.2.9, Unfortunately I saw that '--disable-xmlreader' (from phpinfo() ) was passed to the RPM file when PHP was intalled.  How can I enable xmlreader for a pre-existing php install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.wget  http://dev.centos.org/centos/4/testing/i386/RPMS/php-xml-5.1.6-3.el4s1.7.i386.rpm
2. yum --enablerepo=centosplus install php-xml* 
3. Restart apache
4. php -i |grep xmlreader  and paste result here  if  stil not  enable

Comment: When I ran the second command it said `Error getting repository data for centosplus, repository not found`

Comment: I also tried `yum install php-xml`, which worked and I have `xmlreadher.ini` and `xmlwriter.ini` in `/etc/php.d` but they don't seem to do anything.  `xmlreader.ini` contains `extension=xmlreader.so` and from `phpinfo()` I can see the file it parsed.  There is still no xmlreader support though.

Comment: I just erased php-xml and reinstalled and it works :)

Comment: Good  ;) i hope my tutorial  help  you .